# Why can't I get Array#slice to work the way I want?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a big `Array` of AR model instances. Let's say there are 20K entries in the array. I want to move through that array a chunk of 1,000 at a time.

```
slice_size = 1000
start = 0
myarray.slice(start, slice_size) do |slice|
  slice.each do |item|
    item.dostuff
  end
  start+=slice_size
end
```

I can replace that whole inner block with just:

```
puts "hey"
```

and not see a thing in the console. I have tried this 9 ways from Sunday. And I've done it successfully before, just can't remember where. `And I have RTFM.` Can anyone help?

Comment: Reading is fundamental :) [Ruby Array#slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-slice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `slice` does not take a block, but you are passing it a block, and trying to do something in it, which is ignored. If you do

```
myarray.slice(start, slice_size).each do |slice|
  ...
end
```

then it should work.

But to do it that way is not Ruby-ish. A better way is

```
myarray.each_slice(slice_size) do |slice|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array can be destroyed, you could do it like this:

```
((myarray.size+slice_size-1)/slice_size).times.map {myarray.shift(slice_size)}
```

If not:

```
((myarray.size+slice_size-1)/slice_size).times.map { |i|
  myarray.slice(i*slice_size, slice_size) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `Enumerable#each_slice(n)` which takes `n` items at a time;
- `Array#in_groups_of(n)` (if this is Rails) which works like `each_slice` but will pad the last group to guarantee the group size remains constant;

But I recommend using ActiveRecord's built-in `Model.find_each` which will batch queries in the DB layer for better performance. It defaults to 1000, but you can specify the batch size. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches for more detail.

Example from the guide:

```
User.find_each(batch_size: 5000) do |user|
  NewsLetter.weekly_deliver(user)
end
```